# Python Pexpect and Check Point Gaia Expert Mode

Tags: python, linux, security, gaia

I administer a few Check Point Firewalls at work that run on the Gaia operating system. Gaia is a hardened, purpose-built Linux OS using the 2.6 kernel.

I am a novice at Python and I need to write a script that will enter "expert mode" from the clish shell. Entering expert mode is similar to invoking `su` as it gives you root privileges in the BASH shell.

Clish is a Cisco like custom shell made to ease OS configuration changes. I saw a similar discussion at [pexpect and ssh: how to format a string of commands after su - root -c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124423/pexpect-and-ssh-how-to-format-a-string-of-commands-after-su-root-c), but people responding recommended `sudo`.

This is not an option for me as `sudo` is not supported by the OS and if you were to install it, clish would not recognize the command. The goal of my script would be to SSH to the device, login, invoke expert mode, then run `grep admin /etc/passwd` and `date`. Again, `sudo` is not an option.

Comment: This is what I have:
import...
from easygui import passwordbox
def showhw ():
    uname = raw_input('please Enter your username :')#username for your router
    pwd = passwordbox('Please Enter your password :')#password for your router
    ff = open("router.txt","r")#pass your file with IP address
    for host in ff:
        pat = re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)',host)
        if(pat):
            host = pat.group()
                child = pexpect.spawn( 'expert' )
                child.expect('Enter expert password')
                child.sendline(pwd)
                child.expect('#')

Answer (score 0):

clish does not support SSH. But you can change the shell of your user to /bin/bash instead of /etc/clish.sh

```
set user <myuser> shell /bin/bash
save config
```